# Uploaded file into Gitlab project using api but not showing

Tags: python, git, api, github, gitlab

I uploaded file into the Gitlab project using API but not showing in my project repository.

This is my API curl request :

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" --form "file=@dk.png" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/uploads
```

But this(dk.png) uploaded file is not showing me in my repository.

Comment: Do you really use `https` url or `ssh` url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the upload api you are using is intended for attaching a file to an issue.  Try this, instead:

POST /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path